# Cant access this context after promise return on Firefox debugger

Tags: javascript, typescript, firefox

I would like to know why i cant see on the debugger the context 'this' object. It is as undefined on firefox debugger, but it appears on chrome debugger.

The code of my ts file is:

```
export class MYClass {
refresData(): void {
this.myService.getFunction(1)
      .then(result => {
        this.myProperty = result; // This object appears as undefined
 }
}
}
```

The code of service:

```
async getFunction(id: number): Promise<MyObject> {
    return of({...}).toPromise();
  }
```

Version 82.0.2 (64-bit) on Windows 10

Comment: Yes, its a typescript file in an angular project

Answer (score 0):

if you define a new callback inside a promise, you can not access the parent scope inside the child scope, which means you can not find your "this.property"

I solved it by pass a callback function which was defined in parent scope, it's like:

```
    export class MYClass {
    refresData(): void {
    this.myService.getFunction(1)
      .then(myCallback)
      }
    myCallback(result) {
      this.myProperty = result; // here you can do it
      }
    }
```